# I can't find programs I've installed through Ubuntu Software Centre

Tags: sound, software-center

I've been trying to fix a few issues on my laptop, one of which is the fact that I use beats audio. I've been following [these steps](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=12489414#post12489414) but I'm struggling to get past 2. I installed trusty1 from the link previous and it went through my Ubuntu Software Centre, but now I have no idea how to open hda-jack-retask because it doesn't come up in my apps menu and trying to run it through terminal just brings back "hda-jack-retask: command not found"

How do I find this program to open it?

Answer (score 0):

Its in the PPA description. Which was the first link in the steps you were following. https://launchpad.net/~diwic/+archive/hda

"PPA description

This ppa contains utilities related to HDA Intel sound cards.

Note: as of Ubuntu 13.10, hda-jack-retask is part of alsa-tools. Just install the alsa-tools-gui package from the regular archive and start "hdajackretask". (Note: if you get this error: "Failed to create file '/home//.pulse/client.conf'", try symlinking .pulse to .config/pulse - and remove the symlink again when you have closed hda-jack-retask.)"